# checking for multiple items exist in an invoice/Bill in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've below sample Bill data.

[image]

```
+---------+----------+-----+--------+-------+-----+------+-----------+
| Bill No | totalamt | Loc | Item # | price | qty | type | ProdTotal |
+---------+----------+-----+--------+-------+-----+------+-----------+
|       1 |    10300 | S01 |    260 |  1500 |   3 | M    |      4500 |
|       1 |    10300 | S01 |    261 |  1500 |   2 | M    |      3000 |
|       1 |    10300 | S01 |     96 |   700 |   4 | 1    |      2800 |
|       2 |      540 | S02 |    260 |   140 |   1 | M    |       140 |
|       2 |      540 | S02 |    999 |    10 |   1 | 1    |        10 |
|       2 |      540 | S02 |    111 |   190 |   2 | M    |       380 |
|       2 |      540 | S02 |    888 |    10 |   1 | 1    |        10 |
|       3 |      150 | S02 |    222 |   140 |   1 | 1    |       140 |
|       3 |      150 | S02 |    999 |    10 |   1 | 1    |        10 |
|       4 |     4000 | S01 |   1054 |  1200 |   1 | M    |      1200 |
|       4 |     4000 | S01 |     96 |   700 |   1 | 1    |       700 |
|       4 |     4000 | S01 |     96 |   700 |   3 | 1    |      2100 |
|       5 |     3300 | S01 |    640 |  1200 |   1 | 1    |      1200 |
|       5 |     3300 | S01 |     96 |   700 |   3 | 1    |      2100 |
+---------+----------+-----+--------+-------+-----+------+-----------+
```

I need to check whether type "M" (stands for Main Item) exist in `type` column in any of the line belongs to that Bill. if exists, Then I should have `with M` & if not `No M` in an additional `Description` column.

also I need to calculate the # of occurrence of M & Total No of M.

**My desired out put is as below**

[image]

**Column Header Details**

1. `Description` :- Should contain `with M` if any one of the lines of that particular `Bill No` has `M` in `type` column. if not `No M`.
2. `# of M` :- No of Occurrence of M in a single `Bill No`
3. `Total M` :- Addition of all `qty` values of `M`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
#names of the new columns we are going to create
newcols = ['Description', '# of M', 'Total M']

#function which will build the new columns
def addcols(x):
    nm = x['type'].str.contains('M').sum() #counts the M
    summ = x['qty'][x['type'] == 'M'].sum() #sums the 'qty' of the M
    if nm > 0:
        lab = 'with M'
    else:
        lab = 'No M'
    return pd.DataFrame([[lab, nm, summ] for _ in range(len(x))], columns=newcols)

descdf = df.groupby('Bill No').apply(addcols).reset_index()    
finaldf = pd.concat([df, descdf[newcols]], axis=1)
```

`finaldf` is:

```
    Bill No  totalamt  Loc  Item #  price  qty type  ProdTotal Description  # of M  Total M
0         1     10300  S01     260   1500    3    M       4500      with M       2        5
1         1     10300  S01     261   1500    2    M       3000      with M       2        5
2         1     10300  S01      96    700    4    1       2800      with M       2        5
3         2       540  S02     260    140    1    M        140      with M       2        3
4         2       540  S02     999     10    1    1         10      with M       2        3
5         2       540  S02     111    190    2    M        380      with M       2        3
6         2       540  S02     888     10    1    1         10      with M       2        3
7         3       150  S02     222    140    1    1        140        No M       0        0
8         3       150  S02     999     10    1    1         10        No M       0        0
9         4      4000  S01    1054   1200    1    M       1200      with M       1        1
10        4      4000  S01      96    700    1    1        700      with M       1        1
11        4      4000  S01      96    700    3    1       2100      with M       1        1
12        5      3300  S01     640   1200    1    1       1200        No M       0        0
13        5      3300  S01      96    700    3    1       2100        No M       0        0
```

Comment: inside the `addcols` function `.str.` is working for groupby objects. `x['type'].str.contains('M').sum()`. but, if we did the same this outside the function, it throws an error `df.groupby('Bill No')['type'].str.contains('M').sum()`.  isn't  `x` is equal to `df.groupby('Bill No')`  here??

Comment: No, it isn't. What I am using here is [GroupBy.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html). You're missing `apply`.

Comment: still didn't get it. once you do `df.groupby('Bill No')`, you get groupby `object`. not a `dataframe`. but, `.apply()` takes a `dataframe` right? Not sure, I got this correct.

Comment: No. `addcol` takes a dataframe as variable. The `apply` method takes a callable (`addcol` in this case) and it is in charge of extracting the daraframes from the groupby object, pass them to `addcol` and return them as a series of dataframes. I then use `concat` to join this dataframes together.

Comment: hope you don't mind my questions :).  For example, to get `Total M`, I would've written this code. ->> `(df['qty'] * df.type.isin(['M'])).groupby(df['Bill No']).transform('sum')`, without knowing the above concept. But, after going through your solution. I was surprised to learn this

Comment: I don't mind. If you found my answer or the question useful, feel free to upvote them. That's how "appreciation" is shown on stackoverflow. But if you have more questions, I would recommend to open a new question. Comments can be used for short answers / quick clarifications, but should not be used for detailed discussions or detailed answers.

Comment: I'm one of the two people, who upvoted this question long time ago. I've a similar issue. hence, re-visited again to disect.

Comment: @Valentino is it possible to add arguments to your addcols function? I'm using this solution to see if any items in a list (list is passed as an argument) are in any of the line items. It works if I hard code in the list and call it within the function, however when I try to accept a list as an argument I get an error that 'x' is not defined.

Comment: @rujole13 yes, see here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html